# How to reach website, deployed on Azure Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-aks

I have created an AKS Cluster and deployed a simple asp .net core web site-project into the cluster.

How do I reach the website with a browser. I cant find an IP-address or hostname. Do I need something more?

Simplest solution please :)

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Charles. Thanks for your help! Im currently reading up on services and will go through the tutorial. I will mark our answer as correct as soon as I have verified it :)

Comment: That's the news that it's helpful to you I want to hear :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) with `LoadBalancer` type to expose our deployment to the internet. Then you can access it through the website outside. You can also follow the steps in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-app) about how to deploy the application to AKS.